# Connecting a Label/Button from StoryBoard to ContentView in Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode13, contentview

[Options Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUTJy.png)

How can I connect a label, button, or other element from my Storyboard to my coding file in Xcode 13?  When I first loaded Xcode, there was no storyboard file added to my project.  I had to add one myself.  Then, when I created labels and buttons on the Storyboard, it wouldn't allow me to connect to the coding file the way I used to (clicking Ctrl and dragging the label/button to the code).  I feel like I'm missing something simple but I can't find any solutions online.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Storyboard` belongs to `UIKit`, `ContentView` belongs to `SwiftUI`, the UI design is not interchangeable by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is there something I can do differently to have my Storyboard interact with ContentView?  In previous versions of Xcode it was easy to connect labels/buttons from Main.storyboard to ViewController.swift.

Comment: If you want to create a UIKit based project, select Storyboard in the Interface popup menu in the options dialog window of a new project.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your quick responses.  If I could just ask one more question, and I know this should be very simple, but I'm not seeing the Interface popup menu when I start a new project.  On the welcome screen I click "Create a new Xcode project".  Then it takes me to the "Choose a template for your new project" screen, and I click "App".  Then it takes me to "Choose options for your new project" screen where I enter the name of the project but nothing about interface.  Then it asks me where I want to save the new project.

Comment: Please have a closer look. In the **Options** dialog window the Interface popup is between `Bundle Identifier` and `Language`

Comment: I've included a screenshot above of what I'm seeing in the Options dialog window. I see the Bundle Identifier but not "Language".

Answer (score 0):

You have selected a **Multiplatform** template. This is only supported by SwiftUI.

Select a single platform template (iOS, macOS etc)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness and clarity.  This fixed my issue!